# Implementation of Motor Reciprocating Motion Based on Canopen Protocol

Tags: can-bus, servo, canopen, industrial

I am using an Elmo driver, which is a standard canopen slave station. I use a 2-segment instruction update, non immediate update type, and absolute position instruction setting. After debugging, the motor moved correctly. Later, I set multiple target position points to achieve the reciprocating motion of the motor between the two points. But after reviewing the Elmo driver manual, it was found that in contour position mode, the cache of position instructions can only store 4 position instructions. However, to achieve reciprocating motion, I need to set multiple target positions. May I ask if there is a solution to the problem of cache size being too small, or if there is a way to achieve the reciprocating motion of the motor between two points? Thank you

1、I have debugged 2 command updates, and also debugged 4 command updates without any issues. When there are more than 4 position commands, the motor stops its original motion
2、I can also achieve the update of multiple position instructions through the method of Sleep(), but due to the existence of latency, the program will always wait, and the latency time is difficult to determine. Although it is possible to determine whether the target position has been reached through the 10th bit of the status word 6041h, and then send the target position command. However, there is still a problem with the program running continuously in this way. I need to execute the program myself after issuing the position command, so that I can control other buttons on the upper computer interface, otherwise the program will get stuck in the code of the motor's reciprocating motion

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.